# Number of inequivalent decimal sequences.

Tags: combinatorics

A decimal sequence has digits $\{0,1,2,\cdots, 9\}.$ The digits $\{0,1,6,8,9\}$ become $\{0,1,9,8,6\},$ respectively, when they are turned upside down. We say that two decimal sequences are equivalent if one can be transformed into the other by a $180^o$ rotation. Find the number of different $n$-digit decimal sequences.

Am confused in two counts:

1. Can the property of $6, 9$ turning into each other be used for finding equivalent sequences, under $180^o$ rotations.
2. Can the digits be repeated.

Suppose the answer to (1) is 'yes', and that of (2) is 'no'; then is the below correct :

The only equivalent decimal sequences are : $6\_9,$ and $9\_6,$ where the $\_$ can have any of the rest $8$ unused values, if repetition is not allowed; for three digits' sequence. And, such equivalent sequences are not allowed:

1. Length of sequence $=10$ : There are a possible of $10!$ decimal sequences. The three digit sequence $6\_ 9$ can occur in $10-3 +1= 8$ different places. For the three digits, can have $8\cdot 2= 16$ different sequences. This has to be multiplied by $8,$ to get $128.$ So, the unique (in-equivalent) sequences are : $10! - 128.$
2. Length of sequence $=9$ : There are a possible of $10!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10! - 8\cdot 7\cdot 2 = 10! - 112.$
3. Length of sequence $=8$ : There are a possible of $10!/2$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/2 - 8\cdot 6\cdot 2.$
4. Length of sequence $=7$ : There are a possible of $10!/3!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/3! - 8\cdot 5\cdot 2.$
5. Length of sequence $=6$ : There are a possible of $10!/4!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/4! -  8\cdot 4\cdot 2.$
6. Length of sequence $=5$ : There are a possible of $10!/5!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/5! -  8\cdot 3\cdot 2.$
7. Length of sequence $=4$ : There are a possible of $10!/6!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/6! -  8\cdot 2\cdot 2.$
8. Length of sequence $=3$ : There are a possible of $10!/7!$ decimal sequences. And, the unique sequences are : $10!/7! - 16 =720-16.$
9. Length of sequence $=2$ : There are a possible of $10!/8!= 10\cdot 9$  decimal sequences. Out of which the number of unique sequences are: $90-2.$
10. Length of sequence $=1$ : There are a possible of $10!/9!= 10$ different (unique) decimal sequences.

Taking sum, get: $$10! +10!+ 10!/2 + 10!/3! + 10!/4! + 10!/5! + 10!/6!+ 10!/7! + 10!/8! + 10!/9! -(8\cdot 2\cdot(8 + 7+6+5+4+3+2+1))-2.$$

*Note: The problem is there listed as #16, as an [Advanced problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ekYS.jpg), in a text's exercise for section on Burnside Theorem.*

Comment: I'm almost certain that your assumption about repetitions is not what the problem expects from you. Presumably $160881699$ counts as "equivalent" to $669188091$. I'm not sure whether that makes the counting easier or not. --- I would, however, assume that $910$ is *not* equivalent to $16$. But since the problem specifies "sequences" rather than "numbers," presumably $016$ is on the table.

Comment: So, for instance, for length $2$: We start with $10^2=100$ possibilities. We take aside $5^2=25$ of them--the ones containing only the digits in $\{0,1,6,8,9\}$--leaving $75$ unique sequences. Five of them are self-rotations: $(00,11,69,88,96)$; put those with the other $75$ uniques. Each of the remaining sequences has one rotated partner, giving $75+5+10=90$ unique sequences. As sequence length grows, the fraction of rotatable sequences drops ($1/2^n$), but finding the self-rotations and counting them may be harder.

Comment: @EricSnyder This has been given as an Advanced exercise in a text, in section on Burnside lemma. Also, think a detailed answer will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes, and the answer to (2) is also yes, since nowhere is it stated that repetitions are not allowed.

To simplify things, note that as long as a sequence contains at least one symbol from $\{2,3,4,5,7\}$, then it is not rotationally equivalent to anything else. There are $10^n-5^n$ sequences which contain at least one of these digits, and these are all distinct. All that remains are the $5^n$ sequences which only use $\{0,1,6,8,9\}$.

To apply Burnside's lemma, we need an underlying set, $X$, a group $G$, and an action of $G$ on $X$. In this case, the natural choice is:

- $X$ is the set of all digit sequences using $\{0,1,6,8,9\}$ of legnth $n$. This means $|X|=5^n$.
- $G$ is the group of order $2$, where the non-identity element of $G$ acts by rotation by $180^\circ$.

To apply Burnside's lemma, you need to find
$$
\frac12\Big[(\text{# sequences fixed by identity}) + (\text{# sequences fixed by $180^\circ$ rotaiton})\Big]
$$
Everything is fixed by the identity, so the first quantity is $5^n$. For the second, we are counting strings which are invariant under rotation. The first $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ entries of such a sequence can be chosen freely, and then the last $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ entries are forced to ensure rotational symmetry. This is all you need if $n$ is even; when $n$ is odd, you then need to choose the middle entry. The middle entry must itself be either $0,1,$ or $8$.

You therefore get a formula depending on the parity of $n$. When $n$ is even, the number of sequences is
$$
10^n-5^n+\frac12\left(5^n+5^{n/2}\right)
$$
When $n$ is odd, the number is
$$
10^n-5^n + \frac12\left(5^n + 3\cdot 5^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\right)
$$

Comment: $1/2$ shouldn't apply for the sequences fixed by identity, can only apply for those sequences affected by $180^o$ symmetry. As also shown at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4564194/424260.

Comment: @jiten You are wrong. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma; the $\frac1{|G|}$ is being multiplied with the entire summation.

Comment: This is really interesting; I got the same solution (by a slightly different path), but didn't know about Burnside's lemma, another thing to put on my study list.

Comment: @EricSnyder Can you please detail your approach. It might be very interesting as a check, and another way to view the problem.

Comment: In the link specified, for my post, # elements fixed by identity $=n^5,$ while those by $180^o$ rotation are $=n^3.$ The rest of the elements, i.e. those affected by $180^o$ symmetry are : $n^5-n^3.$ And these lie in $(n^5-n^3)/2$ equivalence classes. The total no. of equivalence classes are : $n^3+(n^5-n^3)/2= (n^5+n^3)/2.$ That tantamounts to your answer with $|G|=2,$ and $n^5$ being fixed by the identity permutation, and $n^3$ fixed by the other permutation in $G.$

Comment: @jiten My approach was: we start with $10^n$ possibilities. We set aside the $10^n-5^n$ choices with at least one bad digit. Now consider the $5^n$ choices containing only good digits. Some portion of them will be self-similar on rotation. For even $n$, we can find those by finding every $n/2$ digit permutation of our good digits--those will be the first digits, and the last $n/2$ digits are determined by those. So there are $5^{(n/2)}$ of those. (For odd $n$, follow the same reasoning above). Then we put the self-similar ones with the unique ones, take the remaining count and divide by $2$.